# in the css overflow:visible is not working.contents are clipped

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap-3

```css
.site_title {
  /*text-overflow: ellipsis;*/
  overflow: visible;
  font-weight: 400;
  font-size: 22px;
  width: 100%;
  color: #ECF0F1 !important;
  margin-left: 150px !important;
  line-height: 59px;
  display: block;
  height: 55px;
  margin: 0;
  padding-left: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="navbar nav_title" style="border: 0;">
  <a href="index.html" class="site_title">
    <i class="fa fa-paw"></i>  <span>Gentellela Alela!</span>
  </a>
</div>
```

I want to make the contents visible if overflowed. I have set `overflow:visible` but still the extra contents are clipped.

Comment: As you are setting some margins and a padding, the element might be exiting the area of its parent. Check if the parent has the overflow: visible property.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You mean like this?

```css
.site_title {
  /*text-overflow: ellipsis;*/
  overflow: visible;
  font-weight: 400;
  font-size: 22px;
  width: 100%;
  color: #ECF0F1 !important;
  line-height: 59px;
  display: block;
  height: 55px;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="navbar nav_title" style="border: 0;">
  <a href="index.html" class="site_title">
    <i class="fa fa-paw"></i>  <span>Gentellela Alela!</span>
  </a>
</div>
```